# Combining columns in Inner Join with AS -solved very quickly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

The query I want to execute is as follows;

```
SELECT 
    s1.sID,
    s2.name,
    s2.surname
FROM
    projects_staff s1
INNER JOIN
    staff s2 ON s1.sID = s2.sID
```

Although, I would much like to combine the fields '`s2.name`' and '`s2.surname`' as '`fullname`'. So when I try the following query I get an error as

`Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

```
SELECT 
    s1.sID,
    (s2.name,
    s2.surname) AS fullname
FROM
    projects_staff s1
INNER JOIN
    staff s2 ON s1.sID = s2.sID
```

When I get rid of the brackets, my results set come back as;

```
sID, name, fullname
```

What am I missing over here? Is it possible to do what I'm trying to without going through much hassle - if so, I could just do the rest via php perhaps.

Thank you very much for responding quickly, Happy new years dear coders. May you have a great one.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder though, I got sidetracked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need concat

```
SELECT 
   s1.sID,
   concat(s2.name,' ' , s2.surname) AS fullname
FROM    projects_staff s1
INNER JOIN  staff s2 ON s1.sID = s2.sID
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you very much. Quick and great help. Much love!

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat(s2.name, ' ', s2.surname) as fullname` instead.

Comment: that works like a charm, thank you very much. Although is it also possible to return the result as `fullname`? It isn't a necessity although out of curiosity.

Comment: Of course, the `as fullname` you leave like you already had it. I just highlighted what you needed to add (`concat` and a space character).